# VirtualBox - Kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu

Tags: virtualbox, x86-64, intel, ubuntu-14.04

Intel i5-2410M CPU running at 2.30 GHz running a Windows 7 64-bit operating system.

I have VirtualBox 4.13 installed.

I am trying to run `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` but I get an error

> this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu

I even enabled the Intel Virtualization in the BIOS settings and then tried to use the image again but I still get the same error.

Is there any other reason why I can't use the image?

Answer (score 37):

My best guess is that you somehow configured the VM for 32 bit execution instead of 64.

Can you share the XML machine configuration file (usually in your home directory - something like C:\Users\Goyuix - in a folder called `VirtualBox VMs`. There should be a folder for the Ubuntu VM you are creating with a file *vm-name*.vbox. You should be able to find an XML tag called Machine that holds that definition. Here is the relevant tag from one of my config files:

```
<Machine
  uuid="{5c71850d-9ead-4b1f-b8b2-9f147f3a70ac}"
  name="Ubuntu"
  OSType="Linux26_64"
  snapshotFolder="Snapshots"
  lastStateChange="2014-07-19T23:16:57Z">
```

Pay special note to the third attribute `OSType` how it has a `_64` at the end. I would suggest when creating a VM for Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit to use a VM type = Linux and Version = Ubuntu (64 bit).

[image: VirtualBox Create Virtual Machine Dialog Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked but now while the image is getting loaded I get 2 options install ubuntu or load it.I chose the install and its asking me the following question "this computer does not have any detected operating systems.What would you like to do? in iso image-I hope if I choose the first option " Erase disk and install ubuntu it's not going to delete windows 7 or any important file from my hard disk?

Comment: That just means you didn't create or assign a virtual hard disk that Ubuntu can install to. It shouldn't be able to touch your windows 7 installation or files unless you go out of your way to share those files. Take a moment to click the checkmark on this answer to mark it as the accepted answer and feel free to create new questions as you run into additional answers - though a site like superuser.com is probably a better place to ask general VirtualBox questions.

Comment: @Goyuix Hello, I do not have the `Ubuntu (64-bit)` option, but only the `Ubuntu (32-bit)`... In fact, I only have 32-bit possibilities. How can I access to the good one ?

Answer (score 1):

**The issue is your virtualization is disabled from BIOS setting**.
I came across same issue but enabling **Virtualization** from BIOS worked. I am working on **Windows 10**. Initiallty you can disable windows Hyper option from 
**control panel->Program and Features->Turn windows features on or off->un-select Hyper-V.** save this settings
Now go to 
**BIOS setting-> select Advance option->**
Here you can see **virtualization** option just enable this option and reboot your machine saving your settings.
Delete any VirtualBox which is present earlier that caused issue. Now click on New option of your VirtualBox you can see option to install 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: The original poster said _I even enabled the Intel Virtualization in the BIOS settings and then tried to use the image again but I still get the same error._

Comment: The OP in a comment under the highest upvoted answer suggested they resolved it based on the info in that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873112/3857942

Comment: In my case I need to disable Hyper-V options from program and features.

Comment: Before enabling virtualization in BIOS setting, I got the same error, enabling virtualization fixed the problem for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884846/virtualization-not-enabled-in-bios