# Virtualization not enabled in BIOS?

Tags: virtualization, genymotion, bios

When I start a multi-core virtual device in Genymotion, I get this:

[image]

What is this virtualization technology and how can I enable it?

My CPU: Intel Core i5-4440

Comment: What's your computer model and processor type? AMD, Intel? You'll have to turn it on in your BIOS settings as you're turning on your computer. Read this - [Enabling Intel VT-x and AMD-V virtualization hardware extensions in BIOS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html)

Comment: @ThisClark, Thanks. That link was really helpful! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I also got the error but i see that genymotion still works even if the virtualization is not switched on. It will just be slower.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to turn it on in your BIOS settings as you're turning on your computer. Not all BIOS look like this screenshot, but this is one example of what you're looking for:

[image]

---

*Copied from source:*
[Enabling Intel VT-x and AMD-V virtualization hardware extensions in BIOS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html)

## Enabling Intel VT-x and AMD-V virtualization hardware extensions in BIOS

This section describes how to identify hardware virtualization extensions and enable them in your BIOS if they are disabled.

The Intel VT-x extensions can be disabled in the BIOS. Certain laptop vendors have disabled the Intel VT-x extensions by default in their CPUs.

The virtualization extensions cannot be disabled in the BIOS for AMD-V.

Refer to the following section for instructions on enabling disabled virtualization extensions.

Verify the virtualization extensions are enabled in BIOS. The BIOS settings for Intel VT or AMD-V are usually in the **Chipset** or **Processor** menus. The menu names may vary from this guide, the virtualization extension settings may be found in **Security Settings** or other non standard menu names.

### Procedure: Enabling virtualization extensions in BIOS

1. Reboot the computer and open the system's BIOS menu. This can usually be done by pressing the **delete** key, the `F1` key or `Alt` and `F4` keys depending on the system.
2. **Enabling the virtualization extensions in BIOS**

**Note**
Many of the steps below may vary depending on your motherboard, processor type, chipset and OEM. Refer to your system's accompanying documentation for the correct information on configuring your system.

a. Open the **Processor** submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the **Chipset**, **Advanced CPU Configuration** or **Northbridge**.

b. Enable **Intel Virtualization Technology** (also known as Intel VT-x). **AMD-V** extensions cannot be disabled in the BIOS and should already be enabled. The virtualization extensions may  be labeled **Virtualization Extensions, Vanderpool** or various other names depending on the OEM and system BIOS.

c. Enable Intel VT-d or AMD IOMMU, if the options are available. Intel VT-d and AMD IOMMU are used for PCI device assignment.

d. Select **Save & Exit**.

3. Reboot the machine.
4. When the machine has booted, run `cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -E "vmx|svm"`. Specifying `--color` is optional, but useful if you want the search term highlighted. If the command outputs, the virtualization extensions are now enabled. If there is no output your system may not have the virtualization extensions or the correct BIOS setting enabled.

Answer (score 5):

If you have virtualization on in the BIOS/UEFI and still have issues there may be a possible **Windows Hyper-V/ Virtualbox conflict**

[VirtualBox does not support nested hardware virtualization LINK](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12350)

try disabling Hyper-V

Control Panel> Programs and Features> Turn Windows Features On or Off

[image]

Note: disabling Hyper-V will "break/disable" other hypervisors that require Hyper-V such as Native Docker for Windows

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too! Virtualization was already enabled and I still had this issue but disabling Hyper-V helped. I'm not sure why you were downvoted. This answer needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue faced by many developers for me this issue is raised when i create genymotion device for android version 5.0 and above versions
here is the solution

**For ubuntu**

During startup, quickly press F12 or F2.
Click on setup.

Using arrows, navigate to Intel Virtualization Technology. ( It might on the next page)

If it's disabled, then **Enable** it using arrow and enter key.

List item.
You'll find "Save and Exit" written on top right corner of the screen.

Now start Your system and start genymotion It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If Ryzen 7 2700: reboot -> F2 or Del -> Advance mode -> CPU Configuration -> SVM = Enabled.

Default value for SVM is Disabled

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtualization is disabled so you need to enable it

**go to BIOS**
->Restart your system and click Fn+f2
next
**go to configuration**
click SVM and enable it (if you have AMD processor)
or 
Click intel virtual Technology and enable it (if you have intel processor)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 enabling virtualization go to start menu

Start menu >> settings >> update and security >> recovery >> advanced startup>>restart now

Now after restarting do following steps

choose trouble shoot option>> UEFI Firmware settings >> Restart

Then afterwards
press F10 >> Alone the menu side bar select System configuration >> Then simply enable virtual technology by clicking enter >> press F10 to save and exit >> press enter to save changes