# the number of cpus of the virtual device has been forced to be 1

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm running the genymotion virtual device and when I start it, it gives me caution
  [image]

What is this caution mean and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but may be your computer has not enough processing power (I mean Ghz or frequency).

Comment: It means that "Virtualization technology is not enabled in BIOS", to solve it "Enable the option in BIOS".

Comment: My "Virtualization" is enabled but I still get this warning. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtualization not enabled in BIOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884846/virtualization-not-enabled-in-bios)

Answer (score 1):

Enable Virtualization in BIOS , and turn off hyper V in window if you have it.

Comment: turning off hyper V in windows worked for me, but why is that?

Comment: nevermind, I found the explanation in the duplicate question commented by smiki https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12350