# Not able to install vagrant and vm

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

As a part of my course I have to install Virtual Box and Vagrant. So I started by running this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

Then I downloaded Vagrentfile from [this link](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2016/December/58488015_fsnd-virtual-machine/fsnd-virtual-machine.zip). Now when I am running `vagrant up` it is showing this error:

[image: error].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enable Intel VT-x or AMD-V virtualization hardware extensions in BIOS. By default it is disabled.

you can take help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27894516/5035803)

Comment: thanx buddy....i think this is the solution but sadly there is some problem with my ubuntu...on pressing F2 on restart it is not going in BIOS instead its by redirecting to OS after some blank screens. Still for your quick reply i accepting your answer. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @pallavbohara , function key depends on hardware, In some system require F2 or in some system F10 , F12 etc. please , search correct function in google based on your hardware . this is not problem of  your ubuntu. given link  will help you in remaining steps.  thanks for accepting answer. :)