# CTC1003: Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, containers

I have installed the Docker for Windows in my "Windows 10 Pro" machine and it's currently running.

[image]

I have created a sample .net core MVC app called "ABC". Then right clicked on the project, click Add --> Docker Support. Then I selected the target OS as 'Linux' and clicked OK.

Now I'm trying to run the project (Ctrl + F5) but it is returning below error.

CTC1003 Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running.
[image]

Note that a similar problem is listed here ([How to get docker toolbox to work with .net core 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869766/how-to-get-docker-toolbox-to-work-with-net-core-2-0-project)) But in my case, I am using "Docker for Windows" not "Docker Toolbox". Also, my computer is running Hyper-V. So the solutions listed in the above question does not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get docker toolbox to work with .net core 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869766/how-to-get-docker-toolbox-to-work-with-net-core-2-0-project)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48785563/1841839

Comment: there is a known issue in github about this. see [Issue #42](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/42)