# Issues with starting virtual device with genymotion and virtualBox

Tags: windows, android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion, dhcp

I am not able to start my Genymotion virtual device with virtual box..every time i try to start my device It shows following error message:

[image]

when i tried to start my virtual device from my virtualbox It has the following error:

[image]

Detailed List of all my full ip configuration:

```
 C:\Users\beetel>ipconfig/all
> 
> Windows IP Configuration
> 
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : beetel-PC    Primary Dns Suffix
> . . . . . . . :    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid    IP
> Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . .
> . : No
> 
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : Microsoft Loopback Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . .
> . : 02-00-4C-4F-4F-50    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6 Address . .
> . . . : fe80::e47e:753b:4c29:a5f1%18(Preferred)    Autoconfiguration
> IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.165.241(Preferred)    Subnet Mask . . . . .
> . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :   
> DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369229900    DHCPv6 Client DUID. .
> . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-89-26-AE-10-78-D2-16-02-DE
> 
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Lenovo Easyplus Hotspot :
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter    Physical Address. . . .
> . . . . . : 00-E0-4C-04-5F-F1    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : Leoxsys LEO-150N Wireless LAN 802.11n USB
>  2.0 Network Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-4C-04-5F-F1    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6 Address . .
> . . . : fe80::cce8:4e5f:3c3c:c5a5%12(Preferred)    IPv4 Address. . . .
> . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . .
> . . . : 255.255.255.0    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday,
> 4 August 2016 5:20:45 PM    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . :
> Sunday, 7 August 2016 5:20:44 PM    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . .
> : 192.168.1.1    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1   
> DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201384012    DHCPv6 Client DUID. .
> . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-89-26-AE-10-78-D2-16-02-DE
> 
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 52.35.184.148
>                                        8.8.8.8    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> 
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller    Physical Address. . . . . . .
> . . : 10-78-D2-16-02-DE    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter    Physical Address. . .
> . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-28-2A    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
> Address . . . . . : fe80::d159:6ed4:c7c:c02f%20(Preferred)    IPv4
> Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 198.168.56.1(Preferred)    Subnet Mask
> . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0    Default Gateway . . . . . . . .
> . :    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268959783    DHCPv6 Client
> DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-89-26-AE-10-78-D2-16-02-DE
> 
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> 
> Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #4:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4    Physical Address.
> . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-F4-D4    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . .
> . : No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
> Address . . . . . : fe80::4d07:55a8:8615:4646%30(Preferred)    IPv4
> Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.21.2(Preferred)    Subnet Mask
> . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    Default Gateway . . . . . . .
> . . :    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 705167399    DHCPv6
> Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-89-26-AE-10-78-D2-16-02-DE
> 
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{4A68A292-E958-49F9-ADBB-B0A6B2E00AC2}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface    Physical Address. . . . . . .
> . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{D8400DF5-8661-42E9-AF74-66AC888DA466}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{FEF87388-CE30-4169-8799-C1EDEBF97301}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{EE6EC7B1-AA13-43F4-9369-16F2EB5820D1}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{925F633E-80F4-4D9B-926B-85932E0FAF48}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{F16B7224-D444-47AB-95DB-CC3EEDD96739}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    IPv6 Address. . . . . . . .
> . . . : 2002:c6a8:3801::c6a8:3801(Preferred)    Default Gateway . . .
> . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301    DNS Servers . . . . . . . .
> . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

I am using wifi on my system...
I tried every possible solution listed on stackoverflow related to genymotion error, virtualbox error and dhcp error or google solutions ...but none work..

***EDIT 1:***

Some Solutions I have Tried:

- manually entering IP addresses, network masks and DHCP server as described on several posts (ie 192.168.56.1 etc)
- deleting network adapters on global options in virtualbox so they get recreated upon start of genymotion.
- installing a new VM for a generic phone instead of custom phone.
- deleting virtualbox and genymotion and reinstalling from scratch + downloading all VMs again.
- freeing up RAM to make sure I have most RAM available.
- changing system RAM resources in VM configuration to 1024 or 2048 or increasing it as far as I could.
- confirmed hyper-V is disabled from windows so that is NOT the issue.
  setting "promiscuous mode" to: "allow VMs", or "deny", or "allow everything".
- repairing VirtualBox

Few Links i followed to solution:

[Not able to start genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/21486549#21486549)

[virtualbox-kernel requires an x86-64cpu but only detected an i686 cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872842/virtualbox-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu)

**System and software Details:**

- CPU type:32 bit,intel
- Host Os: windows 7 32 bit
- Guest Os: windows 10 32 bit
- Oracle Virtual Box version 5.0.26 r108824
- Genymotion version:2.7.2 Android studio:2.1.1

***Edit 2:***
While looking for solution i found that this problem might be due to missing 
files during installation of VirtualBox I  found that "VirtualBox-5.0.26-r108824-MultiArch_x86.msi"  was missing so i manged to repair VirtualBox ..but still no Progress with solution

Please help..!!!! ....I am stuck badly android studio avd is also not working.Please either suggest some alternatives..or solution to  problem.

Comment: Can you try this : `/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox restart`

Comment: @pRaNaY already tried several times..

Comment: to downvoters please specify the reason of downvoting..???

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Comment: 1).Open Oracle VM Virtual box (2).Select the custom phone ->right click->settings->General->Basic (3).Change the type to your current OS (4).Choose Version of the windows In My case: I'm using Windows 10 -so,I Chose other Windows(64 bit)

Comment: Yes I go through all solution of this link...that was possible for me...but nothing works..

Comment: @piotrek1543 I using my current OS type...for custom phone ..this also doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU type is 32 bit but you are trying to launch 64 bit kernel. That's all. Just switch to 64 bit CPU. OS can stay 32bit.

**UPD.**
As far as I see, genymotion is now available only for 64 bit CPU:
[image]

As for alternatives... If you can't afford new CPU, you can try debugging on physical device (USB connected Android phone) - it's cheap, simple and efficient.

Comment: 's I am using...genymotion on 32 bit CPU from around last 4-5 months ..if this is the case...then how it's working so far...

Comment: Older versions of kernels were 32bit - but that's not the case any more. Time is moving on. You can try installing older kernel version (through it will obviously be outdated). As for system requirements, they mention that `OS` can be 32 bit, but `CPU` has to be 64bit.

Comment: 's I tried installing older version...but it's not working.....Is there any other option...other than..physical device....??

Comment: Did you also use older kernel version?

Comment: i was working with older version that time only the issue occurred so i thought that was compatible issues...that why i shift to newest version? Again i tried with older version...but same issues...

Comment: Did you try older version of kernel, older version of genymotion or both?

Comment: I tried with genymotion older version...how to go for older kernel version separately...??